# how to print an array elements index position

Tags: java

let say I have an array of 31 element each holds expenses of a day of January for example; assuming that I don't have any expenses in certain days.
how can print the element and the index or subscript of that element.

> for example day 25 has $100 
>      day 31 has $200 
>      but it print like this 
>  
>      day 1 $100 
>      day 2 $200

```
for(daysCounter=0; daysCounter<31; daysCounter++) { 
    if(januaryExpenses[daysCounter]>0) {    
        System.out.println(" expense for day " + (daysCounter +1) + " is $" + januaryExpenses[daysCounter]);
        monthTotal=monthTotal+januaryExpenses[daysCounter];

    } else {
        System.out.print("");
    }       
}
System.out.println("Your January expenses are: $" +monthTotal);
```

Comment: The above code looks fine.  I think the problem must be in how you set up the array.

Comment: Thanks, it prints the whole thirty elements even ones that have no value.

Comment: What do you mean by "no value"?  It has to print _some_ number, right?  And it looks like it isn't going to print `$0` at all.

Comment: What is the type of `januaryExpenses`? How do you initialize the array?

Comment: @RadadSmo, your array must have 31 elements then only above code will work, suppose your expenses is 0 for a day then mention 0 in array.

Comment: "assuming that I don't have any expenses in certain days" for this days add 0 in you array as value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you were insert to array `$100`  in `0` index not in `24` index and insert `$200` in `1` index not in `30` index for that you have:

```
  day 1 $100 
  day 2 $200
```

You need to insert data with value `0` in range `0-23` index and insert in `24` index insert `$100` and so on with `$200`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are adding value only for the day which holds expenses i. e.

`int[] januaryExpenses = {100,200};`

instead of your array `januaryExpenses` must contain 31 elements. i. e.

`int[] januaryExpenses = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,200};`

then your code will work

```
int[] januaryExpenses = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,200};
for(int daysCounter=0; daysCounter<31; daysCounter++) { 
    if(januaryExpenses[daysCounter]>0) {    
        System.out.println(" expense for day " + (daysCounter +1) + " is $" + januaryExpenses[daysCounter]);
        monthTotal=monthTotal+januaryExpenses[daysCounter];

    } else {
        System.out.print("");
    }       
}
System.out.println("Your January expenses are: $" +monthTotal);
```

Comment: I appreciate every letter you have written , but please be noticed that I am prompted to enter the day I want to enter its expenses till I reach 31st day and I may enter expenses many times for the same day. And logically I may have daysthat I have spent nothing on . Therefore I want to print the number of that day 1-31 and its its expenses.in this form if there is expenses print them and on which day these expenses was spent. And also the array is not constant like {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,}

Comment: The array is only declared int [] JanuaryExpenses =new int[31] no constant values or initializing values

Comment: @RadadSmo, Don't use array. Either use `ArrayList` or use `hashmap` so that you can update value for particular key